# partial screen background image slider jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider

I have an image size of 1680 x 602 pixels. I’m using sliderJs to show the slider of 2 images. The jQuery slider works. My problem is my page shows a horizontal scrollbar after setting the images. How do I eliminate the horizontal scrollbar?

Thanks!

```
<div class="slidercontainer">
  <div id="slides">
   <img src="images/img1.png" alt=""/>
   <img src="images/img2.png" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending where the scrollbar appears you can hide it with css

```
.slidercontainer{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

or

```
#slides{overflow-x:hidden;}
```